# SharePoint List Synchronise only certain Excel Columns

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I have an Excel list resided in SharePoint site with more than 2000 rows sorting by dates and 20 columns.

I wish to extract only latest dates every month and only select a few columns, then to synchronise at SharePoint List.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option is to create Power Automate.

Trigger: When the item is added or updated in the excel sheet

Action: Add/Update to SharePoint list

[image]

Below references should help you to get started:

1.[Add & Update Excel Data to SharePoint List using Power Automate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDOwoPG9ua8)

2.[Update SharePoint List From Excel File](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Update-Sharepoint-List-From-Excel-File/td-p/111477)

3.[EXCEL To SharePoint List Through MS Flow](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/excel-to-sharepoint-list-through-ms-flow/)

Comment: Do you have any further questions about this thread? If you have any concerns, please feel free to reply.